# How to right-align whole longtables

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, longtable

Say I have the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|lr|}
  \hline
  A & 1\\
  B & 2\\
  C & 3\\
  \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

I want this whole table to be aligned with the right page margin. I know that if it were a simple table I could use `\raggedleft` to achieve this, but it does not work with `longtable` objects (for which I have true need in my real case). How can I align a longtable to the right page margin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\begin{longtable}[r]{|lr|}
```

Use the optional argument.

Comment: Thanks, that works! Now I only need to see if I can pass this argument through R's `print.xtable()` function.

Comment: you can set globally `\LTright=0pt` which is the same as `[r]` does.